# Windows script using regular expressions in order to "sort" files

Tags: windows, powershell, regex, shell-script

I have a bunch of files (~10.000) which I would like to sort. The file names look like the following:

```
"variable-name_setting1_setting2_setting3_method_group"
```

All three settings are 1 to 6 digit numbers (depending on the setting), the method is a string (which always begins with f, followed by 3 to 4 characters) and the group can be ignored (I don't intend to order by that too).

I have two types of variables and each of these two types has two "subtypes" (e.g. "ty_x_pe1", "ty_y_pe1", "ty_x_pe2" and "ty_y_pe2").

The optimal case would be to create a folder structure based on the files found (first method, then type and subtype of variable, then settings).

Since I'm not that familiar with scripts (unfortunately I lack the software to write a program and I'm not that used to coding C or Java anymore) I'm not sure how straightforward this is.

Assuming that this is too cumbersome it would also really help to have a script that only moves files (without creating (sub)folders) after I gave it information about the destination folder (e.g. moving all files with a certain method and a certain variable). I hope my question is clear. Thanks in advance!

edit:
Example file names are

```
crb_gdp_g_1600_16_20_fweo2_galt_1.txt
crb_r_g_1600_16_20_fweo2_galt_1.txt
crt_gdp_g_1600_16_20_fweo2_galt_1.txt
crt_r_g_1600_16_20_fweo2_galt_1.txt
```

There are two types of variables (crx_gdp and crx_r) and two "subtypes" (t and b). "g" is just a character which can be ignored.

One subfolder should look like the following:

```
method1/credit_gdp/total_credit/x_16/y_20/z_1600/
```

method1 is identified by "fweo2", credit_gdp is identified by "crx_gdp", total_credit is identified by the t in crt_gdp and the remaining three folders are identified by the numbers. I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: with powershell you can sort with a key you build on the fly, but your details are still unclear, you should edit your question with some more real life examples and your expected results.

Comment: How do you get from the string `fweo2` to the name `method1`?

Comment: I have a list that links these two. But it would also be fine if the outer folder would be named fweo2, since it's straightforward (and not cumbersome) to just rename the outer folders.